# Samba 4 Office365 sync

Tags: entra-id, samba4

I couldn't find any info on if it's possible to sync Samba4 AD with Office 365.

The obvious idea would be to use a Windows server (non AD role) to install the Azure AD Connect software and run it against the samba 4 DC. But since I'm posting here, this isn't (easily?) possible, as the passwords and group memberships don't get synced.

What would work is to have a Windows Server join the domain as a controller and the sync the users, but I don't want to buy CALs. Actually I would wish to not have a Windows server running at all on my machines.

Does anyone know about a scripted solution for that purpose, running directly on linux?

Comment: Did you found a solution?
I'm looking for a way to set the password of an AAD user by the hash-value only, as the AD Connect tool do.
My own question: [My own Azure AD password synchronization tool](https://serverfault.com/questions/996771/my-own-azure-ad-password-synchronization-tool?noredirect=1#comment1296494_996771)

Answer (score 1):

better late than never:
I have found this

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Azure_AD_Sync